# Tanita Scale SDK Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have try to develop an Android app for taking measures over Bluetooth of a Tanita weight scale, but I don't have the Tanita SDK.
I have been working with other biosensors, Bluetooth and Android, but I have to connect to this scale and I can't do it!...

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hi I am working on a similar project. what other medical devices did u use with android. Also did you find and weighing scale with SDK.

Comment: just wondering if either if you made any head way into connecting with the weight scale?

Comment: I'm now in the same situation. Not with a Tanita, but with any bluetooth scale that weighs in grams would do. Any news on this?